# How to iterate over Rc<Vec<String>>?

Tags: rust

The following function doesn't seem to work

```
fn useRcOnSomething(rc : Rc<Vec<String>>) {
    println!("{:?}", rc);
    for i in rc {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

I thought Rc enables us to borrow immutable references to the contained value, however I am unable to iterate over the contained `Vec<String>` in the code above. How do I proceed?

Comment: The error message that rustc gives you when you try `for i in *rc` might also help you understand what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

Rc cannot be iterated directly because it does not implement `IntoIterator`. You can call `iter` to deference it to get the owned string vector and spawn an immutable iterator over it.

```
fn useRcOnSomething(rc : Rc<Vec<String>>) {
    println!("{:?}", rc);
    for i in rc.iter() {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I thought Rc enables us to borrow immutable references to the contained value, however I am unable to iterate over the contained `Vec<String>` in the code above. How do I proceed?

The `for` loop goes through the [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) trait. Because `IntoIterator` works on `self`, that's basically where the buck stops, and since `Rc` does not implement `IntoIterator`, it stops at failure. That is what the error message tells you (kinda, it also tells you that `rc` could be an `Iterator` but that's even less likely):

```
  = help: the trait `Iterator` is not implemented for `Rc<Vec<String>>`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `IntoIterator` for `Rc<Vec<String>>`
```

So the way to iterate is is to get at something which *is* iterable from the `Rc`, you can do that by either invoking [the relevant method from `slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter) as Joe_Jingyu suggests, or by actually getting a slice from the `Rc`:

```py
    for i in &*rc {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
```

which amounts to the same (`impl IntoIterator for &[T]` simply calls `iter`).

Comment: Note that it's not exactly the same: `&*rc` gives you `&Vec<String>`, and the `for` loop calls `<&Vec<String> as IntoIterator>::into_iter()`, not `<&[String] as IntoIterator>::into_iter()`. Both return a `core::slice::Iter` instance, but they're different methods. You can see that if you view the MIR. If you do `&**rc`, then `<&[String] as IntoIterator>::into_iter()` will be called.